# Relay for 3 phase equipment

Tags: relay, three-phase

First of all - I am just reading up and will not perform any real life installations! ;-)

If you have some 400V 3 phase equipment (e.g. a 3 phase motor), what is the practice for controlling the power to it using a relay? Can you use a single phase relay(e.g. TERMSERIES TRZ 5VDC 1CO 16A 250V/30A) and break one of the phase, or do you use a special 3-phase relay that breaks all phases?

Comment: Three phase motor contactor, rather than relay.

Comment: A contactor *is* a relay, but is a special class of relay, optimized for things like 3-phase motors. One reason not to use separate relays is that each one will have slightly different make/break times, leading to uneven phasing.

Answer (score 1):

> *or do you use a special 3-phase relay that breaks all phases?*

A three phase contactor with in-built overload reset and a fused start/stop circuit springs to mind: -

[image]

Schematic from [Motor control fundamentals](https://www.myodesie.com/wiki/index/returnEntry/id/2976).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a delta wired motor (3 wire) you must open at least 2 phases to stop it. If you only open a single phase, it will continue to run, but the other phase windings will most like be overloaded and the motor will generate significant vibrations.  This usually ends up in race between the windings burning up or the bearings failing.  Normally you open all three phases for safety and fault clearing reasons.